# How to get all android app flavor name programatically

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to get all app flavor list in activity, how can i get this? This is how i implemented flavor in my app via Gradle.

I can get only current flavor by `BuildConfig.java` class.

```
public static final String FLAVOR = "myExamIdea";
```

But i want to get all flavor list. Below is my gradle file snippet.

```
 flavorDimensions "igen"
 productFlavors {
        myExamIdea {}
        examLeaders{}
 }
```

This is my `BuildConfig.java` class

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "in.kpis.igen.myExamIdeaStaging";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "myExamIdeaStaging";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`BuildConfig.FLAVOR` gives you combined product flavor. If you have only one dimension then you will get the current flavour. If you have multiple dimensions , then you will have multiple fields , for example

```
BuildConfig.FLAVOUR_[dimensionname]
```

You can get the list of product flavours however.

Edit :

```
myExamIdea { flavorDimension "[dimension_name]"}
examLeaders{ flavorDimension "[dimension_name]"}
```

Comment: I also found this when i was searching this. Please see my updated answer, i am already using dimension but i can't see these variables in BuildConfig.java.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is impossible. List of flavors just not storing in apk.

You can fully disassembly your APK with `apktool` and search flavors in its unpacked/decoded output; you even can analyse raw output in HEX-editor if believe the smali disassembler (or Manifest decoder, or some another) is omitting some info.

You will not find it.

Comment: Okay, so i will find some alternative for my purpose.

Comment: Yes but you have to the dimension for the product flavours.I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, every package will come in a different product flavor
...but one can obtain them in Gradle plugin code, while building:

```
String[] getProductFlavors(@NotNull Project project) {
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    ApplicationExtension android = (ApplicationExtension) project.getExtensions().getByName("android");
    Iterator<? extends ProductFlavor> it = android.getProductFlavors().iterator();
    return items.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

It is possible to add whatever you like into class `BuildConfig` and then retrieve it from there again.